# Change tag name for all resources in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have a requirement to change the tag name of all resources (ec2 instances , elbs, redshift etc).
This can be done using the console where I will have to select all resources manually and then change the value. There are around 500 resources which is going to take time , tedious and error prone.

Change Tag value, for example:
owner=abc to owner =xyz.

I was wondering if this can be done using a single CLI command.I found the below syntax but it requires the resource Id's separately which is a tedious task again.

```
change-tags-for-resource
--resource-type <value>
--resource-id <value>
[--add-tags <value>]
[--remove-tag-keys <value>]
[--cli-input-json <value>]
[--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
```

Any suggestions for a better approach or help with the cli command would be wonderful. Thank you.

Comment: Write a script with a loop to invoke the CLI for each resource?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thank you... i wanted to know if there was a much more elegant way of doing this... but yes as you said script should work.

Comment: When it gets right down to it, not really.  The CLI simply invokes the various service APIs, and unless the APIs offer a batch tag change (not that I'm aware of, though I could be wrong), then any tool you use is going to be doing fundamentally the same thing... looping through the resources and sending API calls.  It would only be more elegant in the sense that you can't see the dirty work done under the hood.  GNU `parallel` will make things faster invoking aws-cli (concurrent parallel invocations) and it accepts arguments on STDIN, which seems pretty slick.